# matplotlib pyplot error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Within Jupyter notebook I can import matplotlib but not the pyplot module:

```
import matplotlib  % works
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  % The kernel appears to have died.  It will restart automatically.
```

An alternative test also fails:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot    % AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

However, I can import the pyplot module from the conda command prompt with no errors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

I got the same results in both the "base" environment and a virtual environment that I created.

Does anyone know what the problem is?  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the maplotlib package, as well as Jupyter notebook, and conda itself.

Answer (score 3):

This imports `matplotlib` module/library and then you are trying looks for an attribute or variable defined in `matplotlib` library named as `pyplot`; which does not exist. `pyplot` is just an interface for you to call other relevant interactive state-based functions to plot.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot
```

In my opinion you should stick to naming/importing convention defined in documentations of libraries for coherent code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  **% The kernel appears to have died.  It will restart automatically.**
This means you have to restart your juypter there will be a cmd window that you could have closed I recommend you to restart the juypter and then

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

if it does not work
open **juypter cmd** from search bar and write `pip install matplotlib` after the task is done in **jupyter cmd** reopen juypter and than use
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Answer (score 0):

Not that I understand what the problem was, but what worked for me is uninstalling matplotlib with conda, and re-installing it with pip. Oftentimes, the conda versions are not the latest, and there is probably a problem with the specific version. As of matplotlib 3.6.1 pyplot does work in jupyter (I tried with base), though reinstallation of `kiwisolver` might be needed as well.

Comment: I'm glad it helped in that case;  however, be careful mixing and matching. For easier maintenance, reproducibility, and portability, in general if anaconda/conda/mamba is in the mix, it's best to stick to anaconda/conda/mamba for packages that it handles. Then resort to pip only for ones that it won't handle. Case in point, see [here from today](https://twitter.com/TalleyJLambert/status/1587835352441446400). Of course, sometimes you just need something to work at the time.